# C# Expose terminology

Tags: c#, terminology

Why is it common in C# (at least coming from MSDN) to use the word `expose`? In most cases, it seems they simply mean something `implement`, or the like.

Some examples of its use:

Delegates ->
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288459(v=vs.71).aspx

Properties ->
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw(v=vs.80).aspx

Does `expose` used in these ways actually mean something, or is it just another way to say `implement`?

Comment: Look at this link ..http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx
when I hear the term `Exposed` I think of Access levels Private, Protected, Internal, Public..etc things like that

Comment: It just means "making accessible to other code", typically by making it public.  Without getting caught in the details, like internal or protected accessibility or a nested class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A type may implement some feature without exposing it (i.e. making it available to other types).

Comment: For example, public versus private access?

Comment: Yes. Private variables aren't exposed. An alternative wording might be "to make available"

Comment: Yes, that's part of it. There are other modifiers, internal types, etc. See Hans Passant's comment above.

Answer (score 2):

in most of the cases **[expose]** can mean making methods n properties available to public in case of public library!

in case of inheritance a **protected method** or **property *[exposes]*** the base class